# Can I do this? Divide the terms inside $ (\frac {(m-a)^2}{2b} + d)^N $ by $d$?

Tags: bayesian, rearrangement-inequality

For part $d)$ of this question I began with the equation in part c and divided all terms within the bracket by $d$. I then used the substitution $d = \frac {c}{E[r]}$ and arrived at the stated answer. My question is, is this a valid operation?

[image]

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Yes its valid. You would get a term of $d^{-(c+1/2)}$ outside the brackets, however as this does not depend on $\mu$, to say that it is still proportional is correct.